# Auto focus entry when it is visible or enabled in xamarin forms using custom renderers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a page where i display a list of items in a listview which has a footer. The footer of the listview is visible only in certain conditions.
Here is the listview footer which has an entry.

```
<listview:SfListView.FooterTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Padding="15,5,10,10" IsVisible="{Binding NewListEntryVisible}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
            <local:AutoFocusEntry ReturnType="Done" IsVisible="{Binding NewListEntryVisible}" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="{Binding FocusEntry}" Text="{Binding cartName}" x:Name="NewListEntry" Placeholder="Enter list name">
                <local:AutoFocusEntry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior                    
                        EventName="Completed"
                        Command="{Binding NewListCommand}" />
                </local:AutoFocusEntry.Behaviors>
            </local:AutoFocusEntry>    
        </Grid>    
    </DataTemplate>    
</listview:SfListView.FooterTemplate>
```

As soon as the footer is visible (as I said earlier it is visible based on certain conditions), I want the entry in the footer to get focussed automatically. How can I achieve this using Entry Custom Renderer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by calling method for getting focus on custom renderers

Custom Entry:

```
public class AutoFocusEntry : Entry
    {
        public AutoFocusEntry()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

CustomRenderer in Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AutoFocusEntry), typeof(AutoFocusEntryRenderer))]
namespace Test.Mobile.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class AutoFocusEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public AutoFocusEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            MocoAutoFocusEntry entry = (MocoAutoFocusEntry)this.Element;

            if (this.Control != null && e.PropertyName == "IsVisible")
            {
                if (entry != null && entry.IsVisible)
                {
                    Control.RequestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = this.Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                    inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput(this.Control, ShowFlags.Forced);
                    inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CustomRenderer in iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AutoFocusEntry), typeof(AutoFocusEntryRenderer))]
namespace Test.Mobile.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class AutoFocusEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public AutoFocusEntryRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            MocoAutoFocusEntry entry = (MocoAutoFocusEntry)this.Element;

            if (this.Control != null && e.PropertyName == "IsEnabled")
            {
                if (entry != null && entry.IsVisible)
                {
                    Control.BecomeFirstResponder();
                }
            }

            if (this.Control != null && e.PropertyName == "IsVisible")
            {
                if (entry != null && entry.IsVisible)
                {
                    Control.BecomeFirstResponder();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the PropertyName (IsVisible & IsEnabled), I get the focus on the entry

Answer (score 0):

You want to listen to the property changed event, in your ViewModel field that shows or hides the footer.

Give a name to your entry:

```
 <local:AutoFocusEntry x:Name="yourEntry"
```

In your page.xaml.cs listen to the property changed event that you want, in order to call the Focus event for the entry:

```
yourViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.PropertyName.Equals("YourPropertyIsVisible"))
       yourEntry.Focus();

};
```

Comment: Hi, I cant access the name of the entry (yourEntry) in code behind as I get an error, "The name yourEntry does not exist in the current context "

Comment: You need to assign a name to your entry.

Comment: I did that, it seems that we cannot access the elements added in the listview in our page.xaml.cs. If the entry is outside of the listview, as a separate element by itslef, then it is possible to access the element by assigning its name.

Comment: if you are using a custom renderer, can't you call you the focus method on the entry when it's done rendering?

Comment: @Neil Yes, that's what I did and got the expected the result. thanks for response